# How does subtracting the character '0' from a char change it into an int?

Tags: java, c++, c, char, int

This method works in C, C++ and Java. I would like to know the science behind it.

Comment: Not science, just math (and knowing the layout of symbol mapping).  In ASCII, the code to hold a "0" is decimal 48. 49 for "1", 50 for "2", ..., 57 for "9"  So it's just math and knowing that the symbols are all in a continuous linear sequence.  (That code will have different values on old EBCDIC based mainframes, the digit symbols use codes from decimal 240 to 249, but the result would be similar.)  So, `char` are just one byte values that are being converted to numbers, that the compiler will treat as integer data.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The value of a `char` can be 0-255, where the different characters are mapped to one of these values.  The numeric digits are also stored in order `'0'` through `'9'`, but they're also not typically stored as the first ten `char` values.  That is, the character `'0'` doesn't have an ASCII value of `0`.  The char value of `0` is almost always the `\0` null character.

Without knowing anything else about ASCII, it's pretty straightforward how subtracting a `'0'` character from any other numeric character will result in the char value of the original character.

So, it's simple math:

```
'0' - '0' = 0  // Char value of character 0 minus char value of character 0
// In ASCII, that is equivalent to this:
48  -  48 = 0 // '0' has a value of 48 on ASCII chart
```

So, similarly, I can do integer math with any of the `char` numberics...

```
(('3' - '0') + ('5' - '0') - ('2' - '0')) + '0') = '6'
```

The difference between `3`, `5`, or `2` and `0` on the ASCII chart is exactly equal to the face value we typically think of when we see that numeric digit.  Subtracting the `char '0'` from each, adding them together, and then adding a `'0'` back at the end will give us the char value that represent the char that would be the result of doing that simple math.

The code snippet above emulates `3 + 5 - 2`, but in ASCII, it's actually doing this:

```
((51 - 48) + (53 - 48) - (50 - 48)) + 48) = 54
```

Because on the ASCII chart:

```
0 = 48
2 = 50
3 = 51
5 = 53
6 = 54
```

Comment: Note that char can be a signed type; 0-255 is only a minimum range and only when plain char is unsigned.

Answer (score 6):

In C the `+` and `-` operators apply integer promotion<sup>*1</sup> to their arguments, thus the result of subtracting (or adding) two `char`s is an `int`<sup>*2</sup>.

From the C-Standard:

> **5.1.2.3 Program execution**
>
> [...]
>
> 10 EXAMPLE 2 In executing the fragment
>
> ```
> char c1, c2;
> /* ... */
> c1 = c1 + c2;
> ```
>
> the ‘‘integer promotions’’ require that the abstract machine promote the value of each variable to `int` size and then add the two `int`s [...]

Applying this to the OP's implicitly given use case of

```
char c = 42;
... = c - `0`;
```

This would be lead to the above being the same as:

```
... = (int) c - (int) `0`; /* The second cast is redundant, as per Jens' comment. */              
      ^                ^
      +------ int -----+
```

---

<sup>*1: If the operators arguments have a lower rank than `int` they are promoted to an `int`. 


*2: `char` has a lower rank than `int`.</sup>

Comment: But a character constant has type int to begin with, so there isn't any promotion going on (in C).

Comment: @Jens: "* ... from a `char` *". The `char` will be promoted.

Answer (score 4):

There's *no change going on*. `'0'` **is an int in C**. It is a fancy way to write `48` (assuming ASCII).

You can convince yourself of this fact by computing the size of `'0'`:

```
  printf ("sizeof '0'   is %zu\n", sizeof '0');
  printf ("sizeof(char) is %zu\n", sizeof(char));
```

which in the first line very likely prints 4 (or 2) but probably not 1 like in the second row (again: in C; it's different for C++).

Answer (score 0):

The numeric constant `0`, without any qualifications, has type `int`. The result of the binary subtraction operation on a `char` and an `int` also has type `int` due to the usual type promotion process.