# Adding and subtracting chars, why does this work?

Tags: java

I’m learning Java through "introduction to Java programming 9th edition" by Daniel Liang at chapter 9 "strings" I’ve encountered this piece of code :

```
public static int hexCharToDecimal(char ch) {
   if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F')
       return 10 + ch - 'A';
   else
      return ch - '0';
}
```

Can someone explain what just happened in here? How is possible to add/subtract chars from integers and what's the meaning behind it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20720381/2792531

Comment: thx nhgrif that helped me understand it

Answer (score 26, accepted):

From the [Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character.

A `char` is represented by its code point value:

- min `'\u0000'` (or 0)
- max: `'\uffff'` (or 65,535)

You can see all of the English alphabetic code points on an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

<sub>Note that `0 == \u0000` and `65,535 == \uffff`, as well as everything in between. They are corresponding values.</sub>

A `char` is actually just stored as a number (its code point value). We have syntax to represent characters like `char c = 'A';`, but it's equivalent to `char c = 65;` and `'A' == 65` is true.

So in your code, the chars are being represented by their decimal values to do arithmetic (whole numbers from 0 to 65,535).

For example, the char `'A'` is represented by its code point `65` (decimal value in ASCII table):

```
System.out.print('A'); // prints A
System.out.print((int)('A')); // prints 65 because you casted it to an int
```

<sub>As a note, a `short` is a 16-bit *signed* integer, so even though a `char` is also 16-bits, the maximum integer value of a `char` (65,535) exceeds the maximum integer value of a `short` (32,767). Therefore, a cast to `(short)` from a `char` cannot always work. And the minimum integer value of a `char` is 0, whereas the minimum integer value of a `short` is -32,768.</sub>

---

For your code, let's say that the `char` was `'D'`. Note that `'D' == 68` since its code point is `68`.

```
return 10 + ch - 'A';
```

This returns `10 + 68 - 65`, so it will return `13`.

Now let's say the char was `'Q' == 81`.

```
if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F')
```

This is false since `'Q' > 'F'` (`81 > 70`), so it would go into the `else` block and execute:

```
return ch - '0';
```

This returns `81 - 48` so it will return `33`.

Your function returns an `int` type, but if it were to instead return a `char` or have the `int` casted to a `char` afterward, then the value `33` returned would represent the `'!'` character, since `33` is its code point value. Look up the character in ASCII table or Unicode table to verify that `'!' == 33` (compare decimal values).

Answer (score 4):

This is because char is a primitive type which can be used as a numerical value. Every character in a string is encoded as a specific number (not entirely true in all cases, but good enough for a basic understanding of the matter) and Java allows you to use chars in such a way.

It probably allows this mostly for historical reasons, this is how it worked in C and they probably motivated it with "performance" or something like that.

If you think it's weird then don't worry, I  think so too

The other answer is incorrect actually. ASCII is a specific encoding (an encoding is some specification that says "1 = A, 2 = B, ... , 255 = Space") and that is not the one used in Java. A Java char is two bytes wide and is interpreted through the unicode character encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Chars are in turn stored as integers(ASCII value) so that you can perform add and sub on integers which will return ASCII value of a char

Comment: could you elaborate a little bit based on the example i gave caus frankly i still don't get the logic behind it

Comment: 10+'B'-'A' = 11 as B ASCII value is 66 and A ASCII value is 65

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of how Java actually stores the `char` datatype, what's certain is this, the character `'A'` subtracted from the character `'A'` would be represented as the `null` character, `\0`.  In memory, this means every bit is `0`.  The size in memory a `char` takes up in memory may vary from language to language, but as far as I know, the `null` character is the same in all the languages, every bit is equal to `0`.

As an `int` value, a piece of memory with every bit equal to `0` represents the integer value of 0.

And as it turns out, when you do "character math", subtracting any alphabetical character from any other alphabetical character (of the same case) results in bits being flipped in such a way that, if you were to interpret them as an `int`, would represent the distance between these characters.  Additionally, subtracting the char `'0'` from any other numeric char will result in int value of the char you subtracted from, for basically the same reason.

```
'A' - 'A' = '\0'
'a' - 'a' = '\0'
'0' - '0' = '\0'
```