# How can we calculate frequency of characters in a string

Tags: java, arrays, string, data-structures

I was looking into the solution of the problem.

```
    static void printCharWithFreq(String str) 
{ 
     // size of the string 'str' 
    int n = str.length(); 

    // 'freq[]' implemented as hash table 
    int[] freq = new int[SIZE]; 

    // accumulate freqeuncy of each character 
    // in 'str' 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        freq[str.charAt(i) - 'a']++; 

    // traverse 'str' from left to right 
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 

        // if frequency of character str.charAt(i) 
        // is not equal to 0 
        if (freq[str.charAt(i) - 'a'] != 0) { 

            // print the character along with its 
            // frequency 
            System.out.print(str.charAt(i)); 
            System.out.print(freq[str.charAt(i) - 'a'] + " ");  

            // update frequency of str.charAt(i) to  
            // 0 so that the same character is not 
            // printed again 
            freq[str.charAt(i) - 'a'] = 0; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I am not able to understand how

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        freq[str.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
```

is able to calculate the frequency of the elements.
and how is it stored back in to the position.

I am confused with it.
Can anyone please help me with it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208308/adding-and-subtraction-chars-why-does-this-work-java

Comment: It's a clever trick, and I don't mean that in a positive way.

Comment: This also only works if your string only contains lower case letters.

Comment: There is no point to this "trick". Set SIZE = [Character.MAX_VALUE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#MAX_VALUE) + 1 and drop the character code arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

The lowercase ASCII letters are occupying a continuous part of the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), from index 97 to 122. If your input is composed of lowercase ASCII letters the expression `str.charAt(i) - 'a'` will evaluate to values from range *[0, 25]*. `a` will become 0, `b` will become 1, `c` will become 2 and so on.

However this approach fails for non lowercase ASCII characters, e.g. uppercase 'A' letter has value 65, `'A' - 'a'` will be `65 - 97` thus attempting to access a negative array index.

Comment: Not to mention other lower case letters, for example the Swedish ö.

Comment: I am concerned about how is it storing back into the array. Even though we havent used any assignment operator

Comment: `++` operator is equivalent to `+= 1` which is equivalent to `a = a + 1`. `++`  reads value, increments it, assigns new value back and returns the pre-increment read value. See [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html).

Comment: @KarolDowbecki This helps a lot!
Thats what i needed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you could rewrite your solution in a much simpler way. Unless i'm misunderstanding it then that solution is far more complex than it needs to be.

```
s.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c, Collectors.counting()));
```

As for the frequency, characters in Java are backed by ASCII codes. So you can subtract chars from each other to obtain ASCII values. Thanks to @BackSlash for the stream implementation.

Comment: Was in the process of editing the answer, accidentally just copy pasted the code and overwrote my original answer.

Comment: The entire process could also be written as `s.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char) c).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c, Collectors.counting()));`