# Java Error - .charAt() returning two characters in a string of numbers

Tags: java, arrays, string

I am selecting certain digits out of a large number. I'm saving the number in a string, and then saving each character as a subarray. This is what I have so far (I'm not finished). But when this code runs, `System.out.print(v[0])` returns "55". I can't understand why. Printing anything else returns a similiarly (seemingly) random two numbers.

Thanks!

```
public class P432 { public static void main(String[] args) {

String x = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934"+
"96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843"+
"85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511"+
"12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557"+
"66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113"+
"62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749"+
"30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866"+
"70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776"+
"65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243"+
"52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397"+
"53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482"+
"83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474"+
"82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881"+
"16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586"+
"17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042"+
"24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408"+
"07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188"+
"84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606"+
"05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725"+
"71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";

int[] v = new int[1000];

for (int g=0; g<1000; g++)
{
    v[g] = x.charAt(g); 
}

System.out.print(v[0]); 
}}
```

Comment: You converted the char '7' to the ascii int value 55, just change the array v to be a char[].

Comment: Try changing `v` to a `char[]` array and see what happens. Then you'll also see that you can change all your code to `char[] v = x.toCharArray();`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider NOT THE ASCII VALUE; the UTF-16 code unit (which happens to also be the Unicode code point for code points inside the BMP)

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20720186/how-does-subtracting-the-character-0-from-a-char-change-it-into-an-int

Answer (score 1):

As Jim said, you need to change the array to be `char` instead of `int`.

By the way, you can use `v.length` instead of the number 1000 in the `for` loop.

`.length` returns the length (size) of the array (1000 in this case), so if you'll want to change the array size in the future - you won't need to change the `for` loop condition.