# Java int array and char array implementation: why does this work?

Tags: java

I am working on the Kattis problem "abc" in a programming seminar class. The question asks you to input three ints between 0 and 100, and have them match the pattern of another group of three char inputs with the case: A < B < C. Here 'A' will be int with least value, 'B' will be second greatest value, etc. I determined my logic but was unsure how to match values to char. Then a fellow student gave me help with the last line but I didn't get a chance to ask about how it worked. Code I have is as follows:

```
public class ABC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] num = new int[3];
        for (int i=0; i<num.length; i++) {
            num[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        Arrays.sort(num);
        char[] chArr = scanner.next().toCharArray();
        for (int i=0; i<chArr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(num[chArr[i] - 'A']); //How does num[chArr[i] - 'A'] work?            
        }
    }
}
```

Input:

> 1 2 3
>
> C A B

Output:

> 3 1 2

So, my question is: How does the expression in the println at the end work? I'm a noob to posting on SO, so any suggestions would be gratefully accepted.

Comment: `char` is an integral type. `'A' - 'A'` is zero. `'A' + 1` is `'B'`. You need a cast to see it normally, because `char` is 16-bits wide and `int` is 32-bits. Converting from `int` to `char` requires narrowing.

Comment: char is assigned to a numerical value of the ASCII table. For example, 'Z' has a numerical value of 90, '0' has a numerical value of 48. 'Z' - '0' would give a numerical value of 42, which is '*'

Comment: tbh, this seems to be a question where the answer is very easy to find. There are other people who've asked this question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21208308/adding-and-subtraction-chars-why-does-this-work-java
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20720186/how-does-subtracting-the-character-0-from-a-char-change-it-into-an-int/20720381#20720381

Comment: As I said, I'm a nood to SO. It's seems like it would have been very easy for you to simply ignore this post, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `char` in C is literally just an 8-bit integer. It tends to be used to represent ASCII characters, but in code it's an integer. Or in other words, `char` and `uint8` are essentially the same type (in fact, one is an alias for the other in most implementations).

This relationship persists, in some form, into Java. A `char` is fundamentally an integer that presents itself as a character. Thus, you can do integer arithmetic with characters.

To examine `num[chArr[i] - 'A']`:

1. `chArr[i]` retrieves the character at index `i` of `chArr`, an array of `char`s. Say this is `'C'`.
2. Note that the ASCII value of `'C'` is 67.
3. Note that the ASCII value of `'A'` is 65.
4. 67 - 65 = 2. So, `'C'` is the 3rd letter of the alphabet, meaning it corresponds to index 2 of `num`.
5. Retrieve the value at index 2 of `num`, and print it.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I appreciate you expounding on this so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy to understand:

Example :

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 'b';

// zero = 0 a this point
int zero = a - 'a';

// one = 1; and so on 
int one = b - 'b';
```

Now in your case:

```
// is equivalent to whatever you enter and the difference of 'A'.
num[chArr[i] - 'A']
```

But if you enter something whose difference with `A` is more than the size of `nums` you are going to get an *Array out bounds exception*.